# Is project import broken on Eclipse Helios?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-3.5, eclipse-3.6

Hi dunno if this question been asked before.
Anyway I have an project setup on Eclipse Galileo at school, and wanted to move the project to my home computer so I can continue the work. The Eclipse version I'm using though is the latest one (Helios), and it seems it can't interpret a project created with Eclipse Galileo. Anyone know how to fix this problem?

I copied the project by just copying the project folder.

Comment: want is the exact error/result you get

Comment: There's no project to import when I go to `Import > Existing Project into Workspace`

Comment: You need to browse for the project.

Comment: @dogbane: that much I know....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What error are you getting?

Look in your `.project` and `.classpath` files which can be found in the root of your project. There may be references to a JVM or paths that don't exist on your home computer.

Comment: I just checked it, and there are no `.classpath` or `.project`. It must have been missed when I compressed the project into tar?

Comment: Yes, if you ran tar with *, it wouldn't include dotfiles.

Comment: just fixed, I copied some existing files and modified it a bit. And it works now